# Adapter together with Factory Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter, factory

I'm using an Adapter to hide foreign API:

```
DocumentTreeNodeAdapter   DocumentTreeNode
          |                       |
          |                       |   
  CommonTreeAdapter  ----> CommonTreeNode  ----> CommonTree (foreign)
```

The CommonTreeAdapter has an adapt() method that returns a CommonTreeNode.
I want to hand out only interfaces. Client code will operate on DocumentTreeNode and the 
DocumentTreeNodeAdapter interface.

Because I want to further simplify the Adapter creation, there should be a Factory:

```
DocumentTreeNodeAdapterFactoryImpl
```

My question is about that factory:

I tend to make it generic, it would offer the method:

```
register(Class<? extends DocumentTreeNodeAdapter, Class<?> target);
```

to retrieve a certain adapter:

```
getAdapterFrom(Class<?> target);
```

e.g.

```
getAdapterFrom(CommonTree.class);
```

But where should I put the registration of Adapters? In fact there is just one adapter at the moment and could be hardcoded in the factory, but for the sake of scalability I really would love that register(...) approach.

I will use Guice later to wire stuff together. Should I initialize the Factory in the Module or does Guice offer an easy way for doing this? I'm not yet experienced with Guice.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure somebody knows how this is done as it is something widely used, but I can't find some samples for it.

Kind regards

Comment: I think that you should not over-design your classes. If there is only one adapter then you don't need a factory at all at this point. Don't think that you'll have another adapter since in most cases it Ain't Gonna Happen. If you create those classes now you'll have unused functionality. You can always add complexity later if you really need it.

Comment: That's definitly something I thought about myself and I think you're right. That whole think above would be used by a parser, this parser can hand out the adapter as a DocumentTreeNode and its done for now. I will check the classes in anyway for later.

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentTreeNodeAdapter` is an interface

`SimpleDocumentTreeNodeAdapter` extends `DocumentTreeNodeAdapter` and contains a `CommonTreeAdapter`  (Adapter)

```
public void register(DocumentTreeNodeAdapter documentTreeNodeAdapter , Class targetClass);
public DocumentTreeNodeAdapter getAdapterFrom(Class aClass);
```

ex:

```
DocumentTreeNodeAdapter adapter = new SimpleDocumentTreeNodeAdapter(commonTreeAdapter);
documentTreeNodeAdapterFactoryImpl.register(adapter , CommonTree.class);
documentTreeNodeAdapterFactoryImpl.getAdapterFrom(CommonTree.class);
```

First response:

just a sugestion

```
register(Class<? extends DocumentTreeNodeAdapter, Class<?> target);
```

would become

```
public void register(DocumentTreeNodeAdapter documentTreeNodeAdapter);
```

or if the target isn't the class of the adapter you want to register

```
public void register(DocumentTreeNodeAdapter documentTreeNodeAdapter , Class targetClass);
```

DocumentTreeNodeAdapter would be an interface and

```
getAdapterFrom(Class<?> target)
```

would become

```
public DocumentTreeNodeAdapter getAdapterFrom(Class aClass);
```

if CommonTree implements DocumentTreeNodeAdapter the next line still works

```
getAdapterFrom(CommonTree.class);
```

but for the Guice  part i cant help u

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I would like to keep the instatiation of Adapters in the Factory, as it should always use the same Adapter. This Adapter constructs the various CommonTree nodes needed. Unfortunatly CommonTree doesn't implement DocumentTreeNodeAdpter. It's the foreign API I like to wrap. CommonTreeNode is the concrete 'Object adapter'. But nevertheless your idea also depends on a kind of initialization concering the factory. Where would you put it?

Comment: I have only experience with spring but it is a IoC/Di framework like Guice. Initialization of the factory would be in the beginning of the program with Constructor injection. I only used setter and constructor injection.